# TurboGears + Heroku + gevent

Tags: heroku, gevent, turbogears2

Following the tutorial, linked below, i've tried to install TurboGears on Heroku using gevent.
[`http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/deploy/heroku.html`](http://turbogears.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook/deploy/heroku.html)

Can't figure out why, but I get there errors:

```
ERROR [gearbox] Failed to load application or server: Entry point 'main' not found in egg 'gevent' (dir: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages; protocols: paste.server_factory, paste.server_runner; entry_points: ) (--debug to see traceback)

LookupError: Entry point 'main' not found in egg 'gevent' (dir: /app/.heroku/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages; protocols: paste.server_factory, paste.server_runner; entry_points: )
```

Any idea on how to solve them?

Comment: How have you edited the `use = ` line of your `production.ini` file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let me suggest you try this line in your `production.ini` file and tell us if it works:

```
[server:main]
use = egg:gearbox#gevent
```

Comment: I still have the same error. even after using this change. production.ini file looks like this `[server:main]
use = egg:gevent#main`

Comment: The error is stating that you are looking for a main entry point in GEVENT package which doesn't provide one. @Xar suggestion is correct, you must use the gearbox#gevent server if you want to serve with GEVENT.

Comment: @amol I am a TurboGears2 user and fan, therefore I appreciate your work and I am eagerly waiting for the 2.3.2 release.

But I think that the documentation regarding this topic is a bit misleading. From reading it, I would also have thought that the `production.ini` file should be edited like this `use = egg:gevent#main`.

Maybe this point could be clarified in future versions of the documentation.